# Disable all the checkboxes inside a list

Tags: backbone.js

I have a form as follows.

```
onRender: function (){
        var user = new models.User({'id': this.options.user_id});
        var userFetching = user.fetch({cache: false}).promise();
        self = this;

        $.when(userFetching).done(function(data){
            var form = new Backbone.Form({
                model: user //,
                //fields: ['username', 'email', 'password', 'domain', 'groups', 'id']
            }).render();
```

And I need to disable all the check boxes coming under that particular form.

How it is possible in backboneJS?All the checkboxes comming under a < ul > tag.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
onRender= function() {
 var user = new models.User({
  'id': this.options.user_id
 });
 var userFetching = user.fetch({
  cache: false
 }).promise();
 self = this;

 $.when(userFetching).done(function(data) {
  var form = new Backbone.Form({
   model: user //,
    //fields: ['username', 'email', 'password', 'domain', 'groups', 'id']
  }).render();
                this.$el.find("#edit-user-form").find('input:checkbox').attr('disabled', true)
 })

 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="edit-user-form">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car  
</form>
```

Comment: Not Working for me..

the method contains following code too self.$el.find("#edit-user-form").append(form.el);

Comment: Knowing the ID of the form now we can search for all of the checkboxes and add the disabled attribute to them.  I've edited the response to show you.